# I would like to create a log of all commands typed in terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, log

I would like to have a log of all command that are typed on the terminal.

I have check "script" but this generates a file with the commands and the responds all together. Is there a way to have the commands only?

Comment: Typed or ran? Ran: `cat ~/.bash_history`. Typed: `echo use your memory`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using the defaullt shells all the commands are already logged to $HOME/.bash_history .
There are several environment variables which affect the history keeping, you can read about those with:

```
info bash
Type: / HIST
```

If you want to apply the setting to all users edit /etc/profile.

Example:

```
export HISTFILESIZE=5000
```

Answer (score 7):

Everything a user types into the terminal by hand is saved into `~/.bash_history`, where `~` is shorthand for the currenly logged in user's home directory. Note also that files beginning with a `.` are hidden; in Nautilus, you can show them by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

Take a look at it by typing

```
cat .bash_history
```

To view your history, annotated with sequential numbers, type

```
history
```

You can execute commands you see there again by typing `!2129`, for example, which would execute command number 2129 as shown by the `history` command.

Note that the `history` command shows you up to the second logs, wheras `.bash_history` is only saved after you log off from the terminal.

Little piece of interesting information:

- Commands that begin with a space are not saved to `.bash_history`. If you run a command like `rm -R mydir/`, you may want to prefix it with a space to prevent accidentally running it again by hitting the up-arrow.

As Joāo says, the size of the saved history can be controlled with `export HISTFILESIZE=5000`.

Comment: However important to remember that if shell terminates abnormally, for example, because of network problems, firewall changes or because it was killed, then no history is written.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in the terminal to search your history.

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. enter search terms (e.g. type 'sudo apt-get')
3. press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to cycle through each match

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want a log of all commands you run in an interactive shell, see [BashFAQ 88 - How can I avoid losing any history lines?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/088)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function for this:

```
function begin_install_log() {
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "No arguments supplied"
    HIST_NUM=""
else
    HIST_NUM=$(history|tail -n 1|awk '{ print $1  }')
    HIST_NUM=$((HIST_NUM + 2))
    OUTPUT_FILE=$HOME/environment/ansible/.install_cache/${1}
fi
}
function capture_install_log() {
if [ ! $HIST_NUM ]
then
    echo "run 'begin_install_log' first"
else
    history|grep -A999 $HIST_NUM|awk '{$1=""; print $0}' >> $OUTPUT_FILE
    HIST_NUM=""
fi
```

Usage:

```
$ begin_install_log some_file_name
$ blah
$ blah
$ blah
$ capture_install_log
```

You will of course have to change the OUTPUT_FILE variable to suit your needs.

Cheers!